# Runge-Kutta-Munthe-Kaas integration for SE(3)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, lie-groups, runge-kutta-methods, eulers-method

I am trying to implement in Python the Runge-Kutta-Munthe-Kaas integration for SE(3) for Euler’s method and RK4 for a simple trajectory with constant speed  and angular velocity in the body frame.

I think I understand how to use Euler's method and RK4 but I don't know how to formulate the function/equation to be solved given what I mentioned. I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: It would be nice to see your work.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I dont really have anything for now because I am not sure how to start on this

Comment: Do you have references to the work of others, at least?